# MS Access 2016-64bit Connecting to Oracle-11g-64bit via ODBC

Tags: vba, ms-access, oracle11g, odbc, drivers

My operating system is Windows 7 64 bit. I have MS Office 2016 64 bit, using MS Access. I have installed Oracle 11g (11.2.0) 64 bit. I have created a DSN datasource using `odbcad32.exe` and am able to successfully connect to the Oracle DB using the ODBC driver `SQORA32.DLL` (Oracle in OraDb11g_home4).

But, when I try to connected via VBA in MS Access, I consistently get the message:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found 
and no default driver specified.
```

So, MS Access can't see the Oracle ODBC driver. I've checked the environment variables and have the path to the Oracle home folder listed.

What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post attempted VBA code. How you specify connection strings can have an impact.

Comment: Before you use any VBA, can you open and used the linked tables to oracle in Access? If the linked tables don't work, then no VBA code doing to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If MS Access is x64, then your `ODBC-Source` should be x64 too. So use odbc.exe.

odbcad32.exe is only for x86 applications running on x64 Windows.